# extension_dir has different value in CLI & phpinfo();

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04

I'm running my `VPS` on `Ubuntu 18.04.5`. I'm having issue installing the `Ioncube` loader because of the following reason.

CLI command shows

```
extension_dir => /usr/lib/php/20200930 => /usr/lib/php/20200930
```

with `php -i | grep extension_dir` command whereas  `phpinfo()` page shows  `/usr/lib/php/20190902`  in **extension_dir** section

Any Advise?

Comment: Is the PHP version the same for CLI `php -v` and what you see in `phpinof()` through the web server?

Comment: Hi Magnus thanks for responding. They are different CLI shows 8.0.3 and phpinfo shows  7.4.16